# Número de Registo limitado mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

Bom, recentemente criei uma pergunta aqui no stackoverflow onde perguntava, como faria para recolher rows do banco de dados com os critérios que eu quisesse.

Contudo descobri que poderia utilizar o mysql_fetch_array para recolher esses resultados e deram-me o seguinte código:

```
$query = "SELECT...";
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

while($dado = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ // Enquanto houver dados ficará em loop
   $a = $dado['coluna1']; //recupera o dado do array
   $b = $dado['coluna2'];
   echo $a."-".$b."<br><br>"; //exibe o dado
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber, como poderia fazer, para não me mostrar os primeiros 20 resultados, só me mostrar a partir do 21 para cima, ou seja, o código que tenho mostra todos os resultados, mas eu só quero os resultados 21 para cima, como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: O stack snippet é usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar "stack snippet" para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai funcionar. Entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Não percebi o seu comentário.

Comment: Você está usando isto https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ em uma série de perguntas suas. O link tem uma explicação do uso do stacksnippet, se quiser apenas fazer a marcação do código use o botão que o icone é parecido com isto `{ }`.

Comment: Ah, já entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Vou começar a usar esse {}

Comment: Porque você não usa o OFFSET no próprio `query`?

Comment: Teu exemplo começa com `mysqli` e termina com `mysql_fetch_array`, mysqli_ é uma API nova e mysql_ é uma API antiga, ambas não conversam.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas maneira, que consigo pensar agora:

1. Usando exatamente o que tem:

   ```
   $contador = 0;
   // Define um contador (para que cada loop +1)

   $limitador = 20;
   // Define um limite (fixo)

   while($dado = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

      if($contador >= $limitador){
      // Se for maior ou igual ao limite irá exibir os dados

      $a = $dado['coluna1'];
      $b = $dado['coluna2'];
      echo $a."-".$b."<br><br>";
      }else{
      $contador++; // +1 ao contador
      }

   }
   ```

> O `if` irá verificar se está ou não com os cadastros a partir do número que definiu anteriormente.

2. Mudando o query:

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE qualquer = 'coisa' LIMIT 999 OFFSET 20";
   $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
   ```

> O `offset` irá "ignorar" os dados anteriores e somente exibir a partir dele, sem qualquer mudança em seu código.

**NOTA:**

> Para utilizar o `OFFSET` é preciso que tenha definido um `LIMIT` anteriormente, veja no manual em http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html. 
>   Caso possua uma tabela gigante, defina o máximo de `18446744073709551615` no `LIMIT`.