# Botão que aumenta o limite do mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, table

Olá galera estou querendo que quando eu aperte na div com a classe "botao" a seguinte linha mude:

```
$albuns = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
```

fazendo o limite aumentar +4 para cada vez que aperto, fazendo aparecer 8,12,16 caixas.

```
<ul>
                    <?php
                $albuns = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
                while($lista_albuns = mysql_fetch_array($albuns)){
                    $id_album = $lista_albuns['id'];
                    if($lista_albuns['tipo'] == 'album'){
                        $capa = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fotos_album WHERE id_album = '$id_album' AND capa = 1"));
            ?>
                <a rel="prettyPhoto[<?=$lista_albuns['id'];?>]" href="images/aconteceu/<?=$capa['foto'];?>" class="mosaic-block bar item" title="<?php
                                if($capa['comentario'] == ''){
                                    echo $lista_albuns['descricao'];
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo $capa['comentario'];
                                }
                            ?>">
                    <li class="mosaic-block">
                        <img src="images/aconteceu/<?=$capa['foto'];?>" />
                         <p><?=$lista_albuns['nome'];?></p> 
                    </li>



                    <?php
                        $fotos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fotos_album WHERE id_album = '$id_album' AND capa = 2");
                        while($lista_fotos=mysql_fetch_array($fotos)){
                    ?>
                            <a rel="prettyPhoto[<?=$lista_albuns['id'];?>]" class="ocult" href="images/aconteceu/<?=$lista_fotos['foto'];?>" title="
                            <?php
                                if($lista_fotos['comentario'] == ''){
                                    echo $lista_albuns['descricao'];
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo $lista_fotos['comentario'];
                                }
                            ?>"></a>
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>
                </a> 
            <?
                    }
                    else if($lista_albuns['tipo'] == 'video'){
                        $video = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fotos_album WHERE id_album = '$id_album' LIMIT 1");
                        $row_video = mysql_fetch_array($video);
                        $url = $row_video['foto'];
                        preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $url, $output);
            ?>
                        <a rel="prettyPhoto" href="<?=$url;?>" class="mosaic-block bar item" title="<?=$lista_albuns['descricao'];?>">
                            <img src="images/__video.png" class="play_video" />
                            <li class="mosaic-block">
                                <div class="opacity_album">
                                </div>
                                <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?=$output[0]?>/0.jpg"  />
                                 <p><?=$lista_albuns['nome'];?></p>
                            </li>
                        </a>
            <?
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
```

!

```
 <a href="#"><div class="botao"><p>veja mais</p></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o OFFSET ou utilizar alguma outra alternativa, [como mostrado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120202/n%C3%BAmero-de-registo-limitado-mysql-fetch-array/120221#120221), fazendo algumas adaptações mínimas.

```
SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
// Irá listar todos os itens de id 0 até 3.
```

```
SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4
// Irá listar todos os itens de id 3 até 7
```

Sendo assim basta usar sua imaginação para alterar o `OFFSET` dinamicamente, baseado no "ver mais" e coletar

Como isso vai depender de caso a caso, uma coisa que pode fazer na sua situação é calcular a quantidade de itens existentes.

**Por exemplo:**

> **Nota:** isso é um exemplo e requer alterações!

```
$('div .botao').click(function(){

    var numeroExistente = $('a [rel]').size();

    $.post("api/proximo.php", {numero: numeroExistente}, function(data) {

      //...

    });    

});
```

```
<?php

  $numeroExistente = (int)$_POST['numero'];
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC limit 4 OFFSET ".$numeroExistente);

  //...

?>
```

> **Nota:** Não use mysql_*!

Comment: O que vai ta dentro do api/proximo.php?  
`$('div .botao').click(function(){

    var numeroExistente = $('a [rel]').size();

    $.post("js/proximo.php", {numero: numeroExistente}, function(data) {

      //...

    });    

});`

`<?php

  $numeroExistente = (int)$_POST['numero'];
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albuns ORDER BY id DESC limit 4 OFFSET ".$numeroExistente);

  //...

?>`

tenho que dizer que o href do botão seria javascript:; ?

Comment: Isso é somente um exemplo, não a solução. A ideia é que ao clicar iria obter o número de elementos já exibidos e então enviar para a página em PHP. Está página seria responsável por ter o OFFSET, baseado no número de elementos informados anteriormente.

Comment: Tornar o OFFSET dinâmico irá depender de  você. Entretanto a solução em si é usar o OFFSET, com dito nas primeiras linhas.

Comment: sim é uma solução evidente, agora como vou fazer ter que quebrar a cabeça um pouco, obrigado ^^